# mod_wsgi and Django app periodically hang

Tags: mod-wsgi

I've got a large Django app. It has two Apache virtual hosts pointing to different settings files, so part of the application is accessible via one URL, and part via another. The Django app uses virtualenv.

mod_wsgi is configured to run in daemon mode with the following in Apache's VirtualHost block:

```
# domain 1:
WSGIDaemonProcess fc processes=5 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP} \
    user=nobody group=nobody
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/python/mine/apache/my.wsgi \
    process-group=fc application-group=%{GROUP}


# different apache.conf file for domain 2:
WSGIDaemonProcess fm processes=5 threads=5 display-name=%{GROUP} \
    user=nobody group=nobody

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/python/mine/apache/other.wsgi \
    process-group=fm application-group=%{GROUP}
```

Every now and again while using the sites, a request will hang. It never completes. I have to use the browser's 'refresh' button to reload the page, and then the request normally works.

Apache itself runs in prefork mode and MaxRequestsPerChild is set to 0 because I've read that could be a problem. This happens often enough for it to be a potential problem - every 100 requests perhaps, something like that.

Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the error and access logs?

Comment: @payne: There are no errors in the error log and nothing untoward in the access log. I can't tell whether the request that hangs has an entry in the access log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be 'application-group=%{GLOBAL}' for WSGIDaemonProcess options, not '%{GROUP}'. The '%{GLOBAL}' is special and means the main Python interpreter. Using the main interpreter often gets around problems with third party C extension modules for Python which don't work in sub interpreters, including experiencing deadlocks. The '%{GROUP}' value is only relevant to the 'display-name' option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've made that change, stopped and started apache, deleted all the *.pyc files just to be on the safe side, but the problem is still happening. I'm looking in the django admin area and this is happening, so while it's possible it could be a C extension, I don't know if that's likely (I don't know how the Python interpreter works internally re loading modules). The page loads after say 2-3 minutes when this happens (but I don't know if that's just Chromium reissuing the request).

Comment: Have you tried a different browser to make sure it isn't the browser? Can you use worker MPM for Apache rather than prefork, or are you stuck with that because of using PHP in same Apache? Finally, try gdb techniques described in 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB' so try and get stack traces out of all threads in daemon process so can work out where it is hanging. BTW, StackOverflow is not a good place to debugging, use the mod_wsgi mailing list instead.

Comment: Actually, I think that the problem might be fixed now, and that there is another problem with Chromium. If I view the page source it's all there, so it seems that for some reason Chromium isn't rendering the page. the site seems fine in Firefox, so I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks a lot.